# react-router-dom v6 not displaying pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I have an app that successfully routes the url, but for some reason the pages aren't displaying under the header. I've looked at the other questions and available resources, but I'm very stuck in figuring out what I'm doing wrong. I am using react-router-dom 6.3.0

Here are my files for reference:
Index.js:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import "./index.css";
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";

import App from "./App";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
    <Router>
        <App />
    </Router>
);
```

App.js:

```
import "./App.css";

import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";

import Header from "./components/Header";

import Home from "./pages/Home";
import Freshman from "./pages/Freshman";
import Sophomore from "./pages/Sophomore";
import Junior from "./pages/Junior";
import Senior from "./pages/Senior";

function App() {
    return (
        <div className='app'>
            <Header />
            <Routes>
                <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
                <Route path="freshman" element={<Freshman />} />
                <Route path="sophomore" element={<Sophomore />} />
                <Route path="junior" element={<Junior />} />
                <Route path="senior" element={<Senior />} />
            </Routes>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Header.js:

```
import React from "react";

import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

import "./Header.css";

function Header() {
    return (
        <div className="header-container">
            <Link to="/" className="header-title">
                College
            </Link>
            <nav>
                <Link to="freshman" className="nav-item">
                    Freshman
                </Link>
                <Link  to="sophomore" className="nav-item">
                    Sophomore
                </Link>
                <Link to="junior" className="nav-item">
                    Junior
                </Link>
                <Link to="senior" className="nav-item">
                    Senior
                </Link>
            </nav>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Header;
```

Home.js:

```
import React from "react";

function Home() {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>home</h1>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Home;
```

All of the pages are just an  tag with their title in black font. However, like I said, none of the pages are displaying even though the url is correctly routed. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I don't see any overt issues in the code snippets you've shared, and I'm unable to reproduce any issue with it copy/pasted into this running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-dom-v6-not-displaying-pages-34ljdv), it runs and navigates as expected. Feel free to fork this sandbox and see if you can add in more of your actual code to see if you can reproduce this issue. If you can then please edit your post to include the new, relevant details.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems right!
May be try adding a **" / "** before every routes.

Reply if you're seeing white screen in preview...

Comment: Ya that's the issue haha. I can't find where I have an issue with my code but I only see a white screen under the header.

Answer (score 0):

You need an `<Outlet />` element to render the routes. Based on your code, it looks like this should be in the return statement of Home.js:

```
import React from "react";

function Home() {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>home</h1>
            <Outlet />
        </div>
    );
}

export default Home;
```

This will render the freshman, softmore, junior, senior components as subcomponents of Home, depending on which route is selected.

You can read the documentation for `<Outlet />` here: https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/components/outlet

Comment: This unfortunately did not work

Answer (score -1):

For react-router-dom V6 you need to render the root in index.js file as shown in the code below. And write the code in App.js as given below.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import {BrowserRouter} from "react-router-dom";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"))
root.render(
<BrowserRouter>
<App />
</BrowserRouter>
);
```

App.js

```
import About from"./routes/About"
import Home from "./routes/Home.js"
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";


function App() {
return (

<>
 <Routes>
  <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
  <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
 </Routes>

 </>
);
```

}

export default App;

Comment: OP ***is*** rendering the root in index.js. `App` ***is*** already rendering the `Route` components into a `Routes` component. This isn't anything different than the OP's code is already doing.

Comment: there might be a problem with his stylesheet. @Crusher101 can you please share the style sheet